# Javascript - como Identificar um arquivo após um upload para o servidor

Tags: javascript, upload

Olá , tenho um script aonde o usuario pode fazer um upload de um arquivo .pdf.
Cada vez que é feito, o arquivo é salvo na pasta /tmp com um nome generico sequencial , diferente do nome original.
EU preciso de um jeito de identificar o arquivo. Tentei alterar o nome do arquivo salvo no fd.append , mas só altera a extensão. Ou melhor ainda criar um arquivo texto com algumas infos sobre o upload e salvala junto do arquivo, para poder ler depois.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                function fileSelected() {
                    var file = document.getElementById('fileToUpload').files[0];
                    if (file) {
                        document.getElementById('fileName').innerHTML = 'Name: ' + file.name;
                        document.getElementById('fileType').innerHTML = 'Type: ' + file.type;
                        document.getElementById('upload').style.display= 'block';
                    }
                }

                function uploadFile() {
                    var fd = new FormData();
                    fd.append("fileToUpload", document.getElementById('fileToUpload').files[0]);
                    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                    xhr.addEventListener("load", uploadComplete, false);
                    xhr.addEventListener("error", uploadFailed, false);
                    xhr.open("POST", "", true);
                    xhr.send(fd);
                    document.getElementById('upload').style.display= 'none';
                }


                function uploadComplete(evt) {
                    document.getElementById('progresso').innerHTML = 'Upload completo !';
                    document.getElementById('upload').style.display= 'block';
                }

                function uploadFailed(evt) {
                    document.getElementById('upload').style.display= 'block';
                    alert("Houve um erro ao tentar subir o arquivo");
                }           
                </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Olá,

Você não consegue fazer o UPLOAD com Javascript puro, sem que o servidor receba os arquivos e os processe! Você precisa tratar no BACK-END!

Sem URL definida

```
xhr.open("POST", "", true);
```

Você precisa de uma página que captura e trata as informações!

Veja um exemplo da página em PHP: [Upload a File using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35253550/upload-a-file-using-php)

Comment: Oi Obg pela resposta .   Infelizmente  se trata de um sistema antigo , sem o devido suporte,  em um servidor fechado , com servidor  web proprio. Não consigo ativar o PHP nesse ambiente. Caso contrário não haveria o problema , meu problema é tentar identificar esses arquivos , dentro do proprio javascript que ele permite.   Como disse no post , eu consigo alterar a extensão do arquivo salvo , logo ele não é inviolavel,

Comment: Sinto muito! Sem o back-end eu não consigo imaginar uma solução! Ele que faz o tratamento do upload...